# On Mac upon reboot, how to make a new daemon start and an old daemon not start?

Tags: mac-osx-server, daemon

We have a daemon running on a Mac server (10.6.6).

We want to install another newer version of the daemon along side it but not start it.

Then at a specific time, we want to reboot the server and have the old daemon not start and the new one start.

**Is this possible and how do we do it?**

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you move the existing file and replace it (rename to .old and move the new one into its place), you are safe to run like that until the next operation that will close and reopen the executable, which for true daemons is the INIT process.

You have to be a little careful if it's a Mac-centered daemon, since some of those run out of launchd and that often only load in when necessary, which means that you might prematurely run the new copy if the old one exits before you reboot.